# Spinner selected value changed after Scrolling

Tags: android, spinner

I've a spinners in the Activity

the Spinners has 2 values

1. Attending
2. Abbsent

The Default Value for the Spinner Is: Attending

the User Will Change some Students Attend State to Absent.

The Problem is when the Spinners Count Exceed 10 Rows and user scroll the page to see remaining rows.

the upper Spinners value return do Default value which is Attening

i try to put a function to save the Value of the selected value from the spinner but i think there is another way to do it.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;


public class AttendantsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttendantsAdapter.AttendantsHolder> {

    private List<Student> students;
    private int[] studentsAttendance;

    public AttendantsAdapter(List<Student> items) {
        this.students = items;
        studentsAttendance = new int[students.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public AttendantsHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_attendant, parent, false);

        return new AttendantsHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AttendantsHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Student student = students.get(position);
        holder.nameText.setText(student.getName());

        holder.attendingSpinner.setSelection(student.getAttendanceStatus());
        holder.attendingSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int selected, final long id) {
                studentsAttendance[position] = selected;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return students.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return students.get(position).getId();
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public int[] getStudentsAttendance() {
        return studentsAttendance;
    }

    public static class AttendantsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView nameText;
        public Spinner attendingSpinner;

        public AttendantsHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
            attendingSpinner = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By Creating LinkedHashMap which will contains key as a student_id and its value as a attendance type which will be used in a spinner.
Below things you need implement at the time of creating Student Model class iteration.

```
    // iterate listitem & fill LinkedHashMap where use student_id(Student.getId()) as key
                // and set studentattendance position of spinner set as a value
                LinkedHashMap<String, String> mapAttendanceData=new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
      //loop list<Student>  & fill mapValue

mapAttendanceData.put("SET_STUDENT_ID_VALUE_FROM_RESPONSE_LIST","SET_SPINNER_SELECTED_POSITION_HERE");
```

**How to Call**

```
adapter = new AttendantsAdapter(ring.getStudents(),mapAttendanceData);
```

***Adapter Class***

```
public class AttendantsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttendantsAdapter.AttendantsHolder> {

        private List<Student> students;
        private int[] studentsAttendance;
        // Here you can also use sparse array too;
        private LinkedHashMap<String, String> mapAttendanceData;

        public AttendantsAdapter(List<Student> items, LinkedHashMap<String, String> mapAttendanceData) {
            this.students = items;
            this.mapAttendanceData = mapAttendanceData;
            studentsAttendance = new int[students.size()];

        }

        @Override
        public AttendantsHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_attendant, parent, false);

            return new AttendantsHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final AttendantsHolder holder, final int position) {
            final Student student = students.get(position);
            holder.nameText.setText(student.getName());
// at very first time before changing from spinner. it will display data which you have set from iteration.
            // and if its updated from spinner onItemSelected than it will display updated
            holder.attendingSpinner.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(mapAttendanceData.get(student.getId())));
            holder.attendingSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int selected, final long id) {
                    studentsAttendance[position] = selected;
                    // Update your mapvalue student id wise and selected
                    mapAttendanceData.put(student.getId(), selected + "");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return students.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(final int position) {
            return students.get(position).getId();
        }

        public List<Student> getStudents() {
            return students;
        }

        public int[] getStudentsAttendance() {
            return studentsAttendance;
        }

        public static class AttendantsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public TextView nameText;
            public Spinner attendingSpinner;

            public AttendantsHolder(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                nameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
                attendingSpinner = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please check the comment in Adapter class & let me know if anything.

Comment: Thanks, i think i'm a bit far to put this is as a Correct answer, now i have an activity i Assign the adapter from it like this **adapter = new AttendantsAdapter(ring.getStudents());** what should i change now ? specify the LinkedHashMap as Null ?

Comment: @Loai check the updated answer (How to Call) & to Create linkedhasmap you need keep code which you have done to create `List<Student> students` where you are creating and calling adapter instance & thts fine if problem solve thn you need to accept else dont. i am not looking for that. :) i know you are far from the resolving issue from the comment i got it :)

Comment: @Loai its not possible to check without your `List<Student>` code . sorry

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain the Position value (Absent/Attending)  while using the RecyclerView.Set the tag to the spinner

```
holder.attendingSpinner.setTag(students.get(position));
```

Comment: not get you idea. could you please explain it more :)

Comment: i tried to solve but maybe i post the code in wrong position, could you please post the whole code.

Comment: put tag after  holder.attendingSpinner.setSelection(student.getAttendanceStatus());